# Using local libraries in a maven project with Open Liberty Dev mode

Tags: java, open-liberty

I have a maven project that builds a war that is deployed to Open Liberty. I am using the Liberty maven plugin:

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>io.openliberty.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>liberty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.9</version>
    <!-- Specify configuration, executions for liberty-maven-plugin -->
</plugin>
```

I am leveraging Dev mode and its working nicely. However, I want to use local jar file libraries with Dev mode.

I was expecting that I might be able to place the jars files in a particular location in the project, and they would be automatically be picked up by Liberty dev mode - in a similar way to how the `server.xml` is automatically picked up from `src/main/liberty/config`. My `server.xml` is set up to look for the libraries here: `${shared.config.dir}/lib/global`, so I tried putting the jars in `src/main/liberty/shared/config/lib/global` but that doesn't work.

One alternative I can see is to use the `copyDependencies` configuration for the liberty plugin.

Is there some recommended way to achieve what I want to do? Ideally I want the simplest solution that will work for liberty dev mode, and also for a vanilla maven build (`mvn package`).

Similar question here leverages the `copyDependencies` configuration, but specifically I am looking for the best solution for local jars (yes, I could use system scoped maven coordinates or install the jar locally)
[How to copy external dependency to Open Liberty during maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58051063/how-to-copy-external-dependency-to-open-liberty-during-maven-build)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good question, generalizing the question a bit, there's maybe three approaches you could use:

### 1. Use resources plugin

```xml
    <build>
        <resources>
            <!-- Explicitly configure the default too -->
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
            <!-- Custom library -->
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/mylib</directory>
                <targetPath>${project.build.directory}/liberty/wlp/usr/shared/lib/global</targetPath>
                <!-- Default, but just emphasizing the point -->
                <filtering>false</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
```

Since dev mode invokes the `resources:resources` goal in its "lifecycle", this can be configured without any plugin config (using the "/project/build/resources" (in XPath terms) elements), and using the `<targetPath>` you can copy to any location.

### 2. Add to the config directory (src/main/liberty/config)

Along with the main server XML config file at `src/main/liberty/config/server.xml`, you can put other files and directories in there as well, and all will be copied over by dev mode.

So you could create, e.g. `src/main/liberty/config/mylib/my.jar` and it would get copied to `target/liberty/wlp/usr/servers/defaultServer/mylib/my.jar`.   From the `server.xml` you would then reference this location as `"mylib/my.jar"` relative to the server config directory.

(This wouldn't be a good fit for the original use case asking to copy to ".../shared/lib/global" but it might fit for others looking at this question).

### 3. Add a system scoped dependency

This was mentioned in the original question.  I don't like this solution as much.  I'll mention it for completeness, but leave it up to you to search out the details. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/364114/can-i-add-jars-to-maven-2-build-classpath-without-installing-them/7623805#7623805) might be interesting reading.